# Can you perform multiple atomic commits using the same connection with MySQLdb

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, transactions, atomic

I would like to be able to perform atomic commits using the same connection object using the MySQLDb library in Python3. I don't think it should be necessary to make two network connections to the database just to perform multiple atomic commits, but that seems to be the situation. Is the only alternative to create a connection pool?

For example, I would like to be able to do something like this

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="1.2.3.4", port=1234, user="root", passwd="x", db="test")

try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into my_table values (1, 2, 3)")
    cur.execute("insert into my_table values (4, 5, 6)")

    cur1 = conn.cursor()
    cur1.execute("insert into my_table values (12, 22, 32)")
    cur1.execute("insert into my_table values (42, 52, 62)")

    # Commit the last 2 inserts first
    # This won't work because cursor.commit() doesn't exist
    cur1.commit()

    # Now commit the first two inserts
    cur.commit() # Again, this won't work

except FailedTransaction as ex:
   # Rollback the actual transaction that failed.
   # Cursor aren't transactions, but there is no transaction
   # object so this is the best I can come up with. 
   ex.cursor.rollback()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL doesn't have different "levels" of transactions within a session. Just one current transaction, and a COMMIT or ROLLBACK influences the whole transaction.

---

I think we can have two connections to MySQL open at the same time. This doesn't require a connection pool. (A connection pool would be a good for other reasons).

```
conn1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="1.2.3.4", port=1234, user="root", passwd="x", db="test")
conn2 = MySQLdb.connect(host="1.2.3.4", port=1234, user="root", passwd="x", db="test")
```

If we get two connections, then we should be able to run transactions independently on each connection
.
But this probably isn't going to work for your use case.  Assuming InnoDB, if a row inserted on the first connection is the "highest" value in the cluster key, InnoDB takes an exclusive index lock to the end of the index, preventing other sessions from performing inserts with higher values in the cluster key. (The second session will block until the required locks are obtained; and that won't happen until the session holding the exclusive lock releases it, with either a ROLLBACK or a COMMIT.)

And the lock issue applies to all indexes, not just the cluster key.

A connection pool isn't going to solve that problem.

---

The exclusive locks I'm referring to are the "gap locks". We would have to work around the locking, if we are doing inserts to the same table, to avoid blocking,  waiting for locks, when those locks are held by a session managed by our program.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_gap_lock

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html